# Dividing over $C$ with parameters in $acl(B)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $M\models T$ and $C\subset B\subset M$ be finite sets. Let $tp(a/d)$ divides over $C$ and $d\in acl(B)$. Can we conclude that $tp(a/B)$ divides over $C$?

Here is my attempt: Let $\phi(x,d)\in tp(a/d)$ be a formula which divides over $C$. Let $\theta(y,\bar{b})$ be a formula witnesses that $d\in acl(B)$ where $\bar{b}\in B$.  Then $\phi(x,y)\wedge \theta(y,\bar{b})$ is a formula witnesses that $tp(a/B)$ divides over $C$.
Is this idea true?

Comment: Your formula is not in $tp(a/B)$, since it also has $y$ as a free variable.

Comment: Is this an exercise from some course or book? Can you assume $T$ is simple (or stable)?

Comment: @AlexKruckman This is a part of an exercise. I do not know it is from a book or not. The exercise does not say anything about stability.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no: in a general theory, it is possible to have the situation that $\text{tp}(a/B)$ does not divide over $C\subseteq B$, but $\text{tp}(a/\text{acl}(B))$ divides over $C$. Even worse, it is possible that $\text{tp}(a/B)$ does not divide over $C\subseteq B$, but $\text{tp}(a/\text{acl}(C)B)$ divides over $\text{acl}(C)$.

This is a bit shocking to me - I had believed the answer was yes, and I previously wrote a detailed answer with a proof (now deleted), but the proof was incorrect. I subsequently found a counterexample, Gabe Conant provided a simplification, and I wrote it up [here](https://akruckman.faculty.wesleyan.edu/files/2021/05/weird-dividing.pdf).

In the meantime, let me point out some positive facts:

1. If $\text{tp}(a/B)$ does not divide over $C\subseteq B$, then $\text{tp}(\text{acl}(Ca)/B)$ does not divide over $C$. So acl can be safely added to the left hand side in a general theory.
2. If $\text{tp}(a/B)$ does not *fork* over $C\subseteq B$, then we can add acl on both sides: $\text{tp}(\text{acl}(Ca)/\text{acl}(B))$ does not fork over $C$.
3. So the answer to your question is yes if you replace dividing by forking. As a consequence, the answer is yes in any theory in which forking equals dividing for complete types (e.g. any stable, simple, or o-minimal theory - or if we additionally assume that $C$ is a model, then in any $\mathrm{NTP}_2$ theory).

Comment: wow!! if you don't mind me asking, what was wrong with the proof that you had put up a few days ago? I hadn't read through it in detail but the rough idea made sense to me (+1)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom There's a common place where sneaky mistakes can slip in: notation like $\text{tp}(A/B)$ hides the fact that to talk about the type, the elements of the set $A$ have to be enumerated by variables, and the order in which this enumeration is done matters for the type. In the wrong proof, there was a sequence $I= (A_i)_{i\in\omega}$, and at a key point I simultaneously re-enumerated all the $A_i$ to make them have the same type as some $A^*$. Unfortunately this changes the type of the whole sequence $I$, so it can't be used in the characterization of dividing.

Comment: If you're interested in the details, I can email you.

Comment: thank you, I would much appreciate that if you have the time!!